# How to grep words from a single string matching a pattern?

Tags: text-processing, grep

Will anyone guide me to grep only words containing pattern _ARA from the below single string.

String:

```
LINK:['IM219MIR_ARA1','IM18Q4_ARA1','SM18Q4_ARA1','IM18PLANNING_ARA1','IM118Q4DYNVA_ARA1','IM218Q4DYNVA_ARA1','IM119EIOPALTG_ARA1','IM219EIOPALTG_ARA1','SM119EIOPALTG_ARA1']}
```

Expected output:

```
IM219MIR_ARA1
IM18Q4_ARA1
SM18Q4_ARA1
IM18PLANNING_ARA1
IM118Q4DYNVA_ARA1
IM218Q4DYNVA_ARA1
IM119EIOPALTG_ARA1
IM119EIOPALTG_ARA1
IM219EIOPALTG_ARA1
SM119EIOPALTG_ARA1
```

Answer (score 9):

`grep` accepts `-o` to print only matching text, on separate lines even if the matches came from the same line. It also accepts `-w` to force the regular expression to match an entire word (or not match at all), where a word is a maximal sequence of letters, numerals, and underscores. So you can simply use:

```bash
grep -ow '\w*_ARA\w*'
```

In this case you can actually omit the `-w` option if you like, and get the same result, since the regular expression here is explicitly matching only word characters with `\w`.

That will read from standard input because there are no filename arguments. If the text you showed is in a file--say, called `input.txt`--then you would pass that as an argument:

```bash
grep -ow '\w*_ARA\w*' input.txt
```

This outputs:

```bash
IM219MIR_ARA1
IM18Q4_ARA1
SM18Q4_ARA1
IM18PLANNING_ARA1
IM118Q4DYNVA_ARA1
IM218Q4DYNVA_ARA1
IM119EIOPALTG_ARA1
IM219EIOPALTG_ARA1
SM119EIOPALTG_ARA1
```

Technically, the output this produces is slightly different from what you showed in your question, because the expected output you showed lists `IM119EIOPALTG_ARA1` twice, even though it appears only once in the text you showed. I presume this is a mistake and you actually want it just once.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `cut` and `sed` commands, use this :

```
<test.txt cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d']' -f1 | sed "s/,'/\\n/g" | sed 's/.$//' | cut -d\' -f2 | grep _ARA
```

Explanation in 2 parts:

- `grep _ARA` would find lines that must be filtered
- `cut -d'[' -f2` will remove characters before your words, same for `cut -d']' -f1` which would remove what is after
- `sed "s/,'/\\n/g"` will extract each word in one line
- `<test.txt` is just a redirection for `cut` and `grep` command

After this 4 previous commands, result is :

```
'IM219MIR_ARA1'
IM18Q4_ARA1'
SM18Q4_ARA1'
IM18PLANNING_ARA1'
IM118Q4DYNVA_ARA1'
IM218Q4DYNVA_ARA1'
IM119EIOPALTG_ARA1'
IM219EIOPALTG_ARA1'
SM119EIOPALTG_ARA1'
```

So, to remove the `'` at the end of each word, we add

```
sed 's/.$//'
```

and for the 1rst `'`, we use

```
cut -d\' -f2
```

So the final result is :

```
IM219MIR_ARA1
IM18Q4_ARA1
SM18Q4_ARA1
IM18PLANNING_ARA1
IM118Q4DYNVA_ARA1
IM218Q4DYNVA_ARA1
IM119EIOPALTG_ARA1
IM219EIOPALTG_ARA1
SM119EIOPALTG_ARA1
```

If you want more details about this command, you can read my discussion with [Eliah Kagan](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52686895#52686895).